# Show customized info of numpy arrays inside pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, formatting, display

Some columns of data-frame contain large `numpy` `ndarray`s.

That makes displaying the data-frame very slow in Jupyter and also in text and during debugging in PyCharm.

Also the table looks bloated and not informative as pandas is trying to display some portion of those arrays.

I am looking for a way customize the formatting based ideally on cell's data type (but not necessarily) so that it would work automatically without explicitly calling formatting functions every time, like `df.to_html(formatters={...})`

I have tried:

- Setting global array formatting with `np.set_string_function(...)`
  but that is ignored by pandas display mechanism.
- The best I'v got is to replace `_repr_html_()` method for EVERY such data-frame.
  not a pretty solution, as it requires to re-apply that every time a
  data-frame is changed,
  like in `df[x] = df.apply(...)`

Is there a better way to define a formatter for specific cell type?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that contains an array, and displays the desired summary:

```
In [90]: class Foo: 
    ...:     def __init__(self,arr): 
    ...:         self.arr = arr 
    ...:     def __repr__(self): 
    ...:         return f'Foo ({self.arr.shape}), ({self.arr.dtype})' 
    ...:                                                                                             
In [91]: Foo(np.arange(3))                                                                           
Out[91]: Foo ((3,)), (int64)
In [92]: Foo(np.ones((1000,10)))                                                                     
Out[92]: Foo ((1000, 10)), (float64)
```

Fill your dataframe with these objects rather than 'raw' arrays:

```
In [93]: df = pd.DataFrame([Foo(np.arange(3)),Foo(np.ones((1000,10))),None], columns=['data'])       
In [94]: df                                                                                          
Out[94]: 
                          data
0          Foo ((3,)), (int64)
1  Foo ((1000, 10)), (float64)
2                         None
```

Comment: Thanks, I have actually started from this, but soon discovered that makes work with the table difficult, as user must remember to pack and unpack arrays from the wrapper class every time they are added or accessed.
That is tolerable for single user of the code, but not when multiple people are using and building on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with displaying dataframes in Jupyter, and I solved the problem with the following code

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import numpy as np

def _formatter(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        return f"np.ndarray {x.shape}"
    return str(x)

def display_df(df, **kwargs):
    default_kwargs = {
        'max_rows': 10,
        'show_dimensions': True,
        'formatters': {k: _formatter for k in df.columns},
    }
    default_kwargs.update(kwargs)
    
    display(HTML(df.to_html(**default_kwargs)))
```

`display_df` should behave similarly to `display`, with the only difference being that np arrays are represented compactly.